# Running multiple instances of Google OR Solver (CBC) results in no solution found (C++)

Tags: or-tools

I am using the Google OR tools (CBC) for solving Mixed Integer Programming problem in C++.
I am following the sample code shown in the Google OR website https://developers.google.com/optimization/mip/integer_opt

Only difference is that I have a bunch of threads(pthreads)/threadpool that are trying to call solver (CBC) simultaneously. All of the threads have thread local data, and hence are calling the solver on their local data simultaneously. This also means that I am ensuring that the constraints, MPSolver, etc are all thread local (none of them are global)

**Problem:**
If 'n' threads call the solver simultaneously, i see that the solver reports "No Solution Found" for all the thread local datasets. However, if the whole process is sequential i.e. different datasets are solved one after another by limiting the number of threads to 1, then I get perfect optimal solution for each and every datasets.
Now, this happens only when the time limit has been set. The time limit is set to 5s using the api solver.SetTimeLimit(). I can't avoid setting the time limit because there can be cases where it might take huge amount of time to get the optimal solution. Different threads can have different data sets which can be varying in size (number of constraints and number of variables).
'n' varies from 2 to 32

**Note:**
Just to re-clarify I am trying to invoke simultaneously 'n' solver calls using 'n' threads (each thread calls it's own solver.solve()).

I am not trying to distribute the work of a single solver among 'n' threads.

Comment: Which version of or-tools ? which platform ? How did you build it ?

Comment: Version: or-tools_--64bit_v7.5.7466. (Didn't build it, downloaded the binary from or -tools link and hence using the pre-built binary.) 
Platform: CentOs Linux (7.5.1804)

Comment: I checked there are no static objects in the cbc interface code. Maybe in CBC itself. I remember there is a flag to specify that CBC should be MT safe. I will check if it was compiled correctly.

Comment: In the meantime, if your problem does not contains continuous variables, you can use the SAT_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING. In that case, set the parameters (as string) num_search_workers:8,catch_sigint_signal:false

Comment: Thank you very much for suggesting an alternate method.
However, my problem has a mix of integer and continuous variables.

Comment: @LaurentPerron: I can also try newer versions of Google OR if they are thread-safe from CBC perspective. If so please let me know the build version number, so that I can test it.
Thanks.